# ActionBar popup in Material design

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Google saturday released a brand new version of AppCompat, which makes the ActionBar really similar to the ActionBar used by Google Chrome.

I'm wondering if there's any way to tell AppCompat to use the same style for the ActionBar popup as Google Chrome (the animation effect, the touch feedback etc.).

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: No, this is not built in. Chrome has a custom implementation that is not using PopupMenu. It is not compatible with the standard ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

You must use Toolbar to do those effects.

The animations you can achieve by code.

A good reading about the first steps for Material Design can be found here: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/